# How do I implement different views in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, view

I'm trying to implement a simulation for blockchain. The blockchain consists of a network with miners. In my example I have 10 miners. Each of these miners have a candidate block, in which they put in transactions from the transaction pool. The transactions come from the network and get put into the transaction pool.
Example: If Miner 1 puts Transaction A into his candidate block, Transaction A should still be available in the transaction pool of Miners 2-10. It's still available because the transaction hasn't been mined yet. If the block of Miner 1 gets mined, then Transaction A should be deleted from every transaction pool.

The problem is, how to implement the different views for each node. How do I switch between the nodes and keep the transaction pool attached to each node?

I'm using a grid layout in my project. One grid displays the network with all the nodes. One grid displays the blocks of each node. One grid displays the global transactions, which are stored in a pool. But each node should store the transactions locally, which means if node 1 takes one transaction, the transaction should still be in for node 2 and the others.

Miner-View.ts:

```
export class MinerViewComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
          transaction: Transaction;
          displayedColumns: string[] = ['sender', 'recipient', 'amount', 'fee'];
          dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Transaction>(ELEMENT_DATA);
          temp: Transaction[] = [];
          blockNumber = 1;
          previousHash = '00000000000000000000000000000000';
          blockHash: string = this.generateFirstHash();
          blockHashList: string[] = [];

      panelOpenState = false;

      message: any;
      subscription: Subscription;

      constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef, private emitTransactionService: EmitTransactionService,
                  private messageService: MessageService) {
        this.subscription = this.messageService.getMessage().subscribe(message => {
          this.message = message;
          this.sendBlockToBC();
          this.clearBlock();
        });
      }

      ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.emitTransactionService.row$.subscribe(transaction => {
            this.transaction = transaction;
            this.temp = this.dataSource.data.slice();
            this.temp.push(this.transaction);
            this.dataSource.data = this.temp;
            this.ref.detectChanges();
          }
        );
        this.temp = this.dataSource.data.slice();
        this.temp.pop();
        this.dataSource.data = this.temp;
        this.ref.detectChanges();
      }

      /** This method clears the current block of the miner (transactions only), when a new block has been added to the
       * blockchain. **/
      clearBlock() {
        this.ref.detectChanges();
        console.log('Transactions none.');
      }

      sendMessage(): void {
        this.messageService.sendMessage2('Message from miner view component to block-card component!');
      }

      /** This method puts the block from the active miner in the blockchain (when he got the proof-of-...). **/
      sendBlockToBC() {
        const block = new Block(this.blockNumber, this.temp, this.previousHash, this.blockHash);
        this.emitTransactionService.emitBlock(block);
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(block);
            this.temp = null;
            this.dataSource = undefined; // to empty the table in the miner view component
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Transaction>(ELEMENT_DATA); // create new datasource to fill the table,
            // since the old one gives an error
            this.generateBlockHash();
            this.raiseBlockNumber();
            this.sendMessage();
          },
          100);

      }
```

Transaction-pool-component.ts:

```
export class TransactionPoolComponent implements OnInit {
          displayedColumns: string[] = ['select', 'sender', 'recipient', 'amount', 'fee'];
          dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Transaction>(ELEMENT_DATA);
          selection = new SelectionModel<Transaction>(true, []);
          transaction: Transaction;
          temp: Transaction[];

      constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef, private emitTransactionService: EmitTransactionService) {
      }

      /** This method gets the selected row as input. The selected row then gets deleted from the transaction
       * pool and appears in the block of the miner. **/
      putTXInBlock(row) {
        this.temp = this.dataSource.data.slice();
        for (let i = 0; i < this.temp.length; i++) {
          if (JSON.stringify(row) === JSON.stringify(this.temp[i]) ) {
            this.temp.splice(i, 1);
            break;
          }
        }
        this.dataSource.data = this.temp;
        this.ref.detectChanges();
        this.emitTransactionService.emitRow(row);
      }

      ngOnInit() {
          this.emitTransactionService.transaction$.subscribe(transaction => {
              this.transaction = transaction;
              this.temp = this.dataSource.data.slice();
              this.temp.push(this.transaction);
              this.dataSource.data = this.temp;
              this.ref.detectChanges();
            }
          );
          this.temp = this.dataSource.data.slice();
          this.temp.pop();
          this.dataSource.data = this.temp;
          this.ref.detectChanges();
      }
    }
```

At the moment I just implemented it for node 1. I think I have to change the whole concept of my code, or may it work with a small change? I want it to work for all nodes.

The problem: At the moment I don't know how to manage the data sources separately for all 10 nodes. Because each node should have its own data source with all the global transactions. Another thing is how to get all the 10 nodes into the interface. My idea was to implement a `< >` button, where I can switch between 1-10. But what's the easiest way to do that? With views for each node I mean that every node has an own transaction pool, where all the global transactions get put in. And each node then can put these transactions into their own block. BUT these transactions don't get deleted for the other nodes. My problem is relative to UX and data model.

If you need more information or something is unclear please tell me. I will try to improve the question then.

The network with 10 nodes:

[image]

The upper block should display the information from the block of the node. The lower block should display the pool with the transactions, which in this case belong to node 1.

[image]

Comment: You should provide more context, you never tell what you are trying to implement, what's the purpose of your app? It feels like you have a very functional problem, how to represent it technically within Angular. We won't be able to answer you without precise question.

Comment: I tried to describe it better in the first lines. Hope you get a better insight, of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Ok the context is much clearer. But what is the problem you are facing, shortly? Data access or update? Same data at several places? What do you mean by "views by node"? Is your problem relative to UX or just your data model?

Comment: I updated the question. Hope it is clearer.